# How do I do the following using Lambda or Linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have this function that needs to be converted to a lambda statement:

```
public int someFunction()
{
    int pCount = 0;
    foreach (Top top in Tops)
    {
        foreach (P p in top.TopPs)
        {
            pCount++;
        }
    }
    return pCount;
}
```

Added more clarity:

Tops and top.TopPs extends ObservableCollection

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative method:

```
    int pCount = (from t in Tops
                  from p in t.TopPs
                  select p).Count();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int count = Tops.Sum(top => top.TopPs.Count());
```

Comment: +1 for being literally the exact same code I was about to submit as my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean a LINQ query?

```
int count = Tops.SelectMany(x => x.TopPs).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sum LINQ operator over count of the the nested collection:

```
Tops.Sum(t=>t.TopPs.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var pCount = Tops.Sum(t=>t.TopPs.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
var cnt = Tops.Select<Top, int>(q => q.TopPs.Count()).Sum();
```

got it?

Answer (score -1):

You can just simply use Count() for that, and it's available as an extension method.

For example:

```
Tops.Count();
```

Comment: This answer counts the top-level elements not the TopPs inside them.